# Redefining function which is in html <script> element

Tags: javascript, html

index.html:

```
<script id="change">
    function methods(){
        return 1;
    }
</script>
```

js.js:

```
...
button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    document.querySelector("#change").innerHTML = `
        function methods(){
            return 0;
        }
    `;
}
...
```

Console before clicking button:

```
>>>methods();
1
```

Console after clicking button:

```
>>>methods();
1
```

How can I update this function?

Comment: I've fixed the Markdown issues (code blocks need an empty line before them).

Comment: can't you just use `let function1 = function2` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of rewriting the script tag content, just overwrite the `methods` function.

This can be demonstrated easily using the following snippet:

```js
console.log(methods());

methods = function() {
  return 0;
}

console.log(methods());
```

```html
<script id="change">
    function methods(){
        return 1;
    }
</script>
```

In the case of your code, in the event handler just do the same:

```
...
button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  methods = function() {
    return 0;
  }
});
...
```

**Edit following OP comment**

OP has commented stating that the function content is read out of a database and is stored in a `string`.  This changes the solution required to:

```js
console.log(methods());

var functionText = "return 0;";
methods = Function(functionText);

console.log(methods());
```

```html
<script id="change">
    function methods(){
        return 1;
    }
</script>
```

In your original code, this would then look like:

```
...
button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  methods = Function("return 0;");
});
...
```

Comment: I am sure this works, but, I am getting some js from database as string

Comment: @JasurbekLazizjonov Probably would have been useful to have put that in the question as that does change the problem.  Let me have a think and update the answer

Comment: @JasurbekLazizjonov I've updated to reflect the requirement you mentioned in your comment

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.onclick = function() { document.querySelector("#change").innerHTML = `
        function methods(){
            return 0;
        }
    `;
}
```

```html
<script id="change">
    function methods(){
        return 1;
    }
</script>

<button>button</button>
```